# How to verify a method call with Enum Parameter using Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

```
verify(email.create(xx.E));
```

Below is the Enum

```
public enum xx {

     A,B,C,D,E

    }
```

Let me know if there is a way verify if **create Method is called** with enum as a parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the method out

```
//verify method invocation.
verify(email).create(xx.E);
```

Reference  [Let's verify some behaviour!](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#1)